# WPF and SlimDX (DirectX 11) interop

Tags: wpf, slimdx, directx-11

Hello I've managed to integrate SlimDX and DirectX 11 graphics in a WPF application by using D3DImage and shared textures. However, but I'm getting some really poor performance when rendering simple scenes (e.g. GameOfLife in the SlimDX samples) at high resolution (2560x1440).

I've tried doing some performance profiling of my render method and it looks like most of the time is spent on locking the D3DImage when invalidating the backbuffer.

```
_d3dImage.Lock(); // <- this call takes 78,5 % of the time when rendering the frame
_d3dImage.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, _d3dImage.PixelWidth, _d3dImage.PixelHeight));
_d3dImage.Unlock();
```

A lot of time is spent flusing the device after drawing:

```
_device.ImmediateContext.Flush(); // <- 20,6% of the time when rendering the frame
```

Anyone know the problem and how to optimize this? Can you expect to get descent performance when integrating WPF and SlimDX?

Comment: Locking blocks the thread until the UI thread stops reading the back buffer, and flushing is pretty expensive so these results aren't unusual. What are your actual performance figures? Does your GPU support compute shaders? If not then that would be running in software (ie at the speed of smell).

Comment: Looks like the problem might have something to do with the compute shader used in the GameOfLife sample. If I disable it the frame-rate goes back up to 60fps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're seeing performance issues on locking and flushing calls (which are points where the GPU needs to sync with the CPU), I'd guess that your program is severely GPU bound, and the CPU has to keep stalling waiting for it to catch up. That's also born out by the performance increase when disabling the compute shader.

I'm not sure what to tell you at that point, except that if that guess is right, it would appear that your card can't handle the load.

Comment: Thanks, it would appear so. Although I'm running on a Radeon HD5850 that should handle the load I would imagine - the shader is not that complicated.

Comment: That's definitely not all there is to it. I have the same problem, with Lock() taking forever, and hosting DirectX in Windows Forms results in much better performance.

Comment: That is interesting. Perhaps WPF + Dx wasn't meant to be.